# How do you write a conditional to ignore a null value for an image in gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby, strapi

Strapi has an option to make an image required or not, but regardless of whether you select the required button, it makes it required and renders a null value in gatsby. How can I programmatically tell gatsby to render just the rich text if that is selected and ignore the null image value if not picture is uploaded? I wanted to do something like {image && ()}, but not sure how to map that..

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown"
import Image from "gatsby-image"

//import Layout from "../components/layout"

const ComponentName = ({ data }) => {
  const { title, layout } = data.strapiBasics;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
        {layout.map(item =>  {
          return (
            <span key={item.id}><ReactMarkdown source={item.rich_text} />
            <Image fluid={item.image.childImageSharp.fluid} /> 
            </span>
          )
        })}
    </div>
  )
}


export const query = graphql`
  query BasicQuery($slug: String!) {
    strapiBasics(Slug: {eq: $slug}) {
      title:  Title
      slug: Slug
      layout: Layout {
        id
        rich_text
        image: Image {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default ComponentName
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
       {layout.map(item => { 
         return (
           <span key={item.id}><ReactMarkdown source={item.rich_text} />           
           {item.image &&  <Image fluid={item.image.childImageSharp.fluid} />}           
         </span>           
        ) 
       })}
    </div>
  );
```

*Note: you may need to change the `item.Image` to check if it meets the condition.*

Since you are aliasing your GraphQL query:

```
image: Image {...}
```

Your object will `Image`, not `image`, and so on with the rest.

You don't need to add the `&&` logical operator inside, you just can return an image if it exists or return a markdown if don't.

Comment: thanks Ferran, but I still have the issue.TypeError: Cannot read property 'childImageSharp' of null. Ugh I'm so frustrated.

Comment: Then look for `item.image` instead of  `item.image.childImageSharp`

Comment: same issue. I think the problem is that the if statement needs to show that item.image is a data prop so it needs to be something like if ({item.image}), but that doesn't work.

Comment: Try to debug to show what's inside `layout`, inside `item`, and so on to check where's the mistake and place the condition with it. It doesn't make sense the curly braces that you mentioned since `data` is destructurated as a `prop` itself...

Comment: Take a look at your alias in your GraphQL query. You named `Image` instead of `image`. You aliased everything so your structure have changed.

Comment: this is what finally worked for me thanks for trying to help Ferran!                                      
        `...
        {layout.map(item => {
          return (
          <span key={item.id}><ReactMarkdown source={item.rich_text} />
          {item.image &&  (<Image fluid={item.image.childImageSharp.fluid} />)}
          </span>
          )
        })}
     ...
`